# Is there simple applet mixer for pulseaudio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

With new openSUSE 13.2 I find huge problem with sound -- with ALSA I lost the line out, and besides the sound was too quiet in general (today max out, is yesterday half). With help of pulseaudio plugins for ALSA I was able to get decent level of "noise".

However there is next problem -- simplistic mixer that would sit in systray. I need something that popups a frame with slider for volume and button for mute. Not huge dialog with 10 sliders, 5 options, etc.

I prefer something that does not bring ton of dependencies.